# How to create FORTRAN Cell?

Tags: programming, front-end, external-calls, fortran

I want to create a FORTRAN cell in Mathematica.

```
pr = "PROGRAM test
Integer::a, b
a=3
b=9
print*,  a, ' +', b, ' = ', a + b
print*,  a, ' *', b, ' = ', a * b
END Program test
";

GFortran[inp_] := (
Export["temp1.f90", inp, "Text"];
Column@ReadList["!gfortran temp1.f90 && a.exe", String])
```

The function works fine:

```
GFortran[pr]
DeleteFile[{"temp1.f90", "a.exe"}]
```

[image]

Now with a cell

```
(CellPrint[
 TextCell[
 pr, "Program",
 Evaluatable -> True, 
 CellEvaluationFunction -> (GFortran[#] &), 
 CellFrameLabels -> {{None, "Fortran"}, {None, None}}]]; 
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellContents])
```

[image]

File `temp1.f90` is created, but not compiled, so there is no output. What could be wrong?

**Edit:**

I changed `GFortran` to

```
GFortran[inp_] := (
Export["temp1.f90", inp, "Text"];
Get["!gfortran temp1.f90"];
Column@ReadList["!a.exe", String])
```

Now the FORTRAN cell will have output, but only if `temp1.f90` was compiled before cell execution

Comment: What happens if you try something generic like `ReadList["!pause", String]`, or a simple file copy, etc., to see if the command is being run?

Comment: For `CellEvaluationFunction -> ReadList["!pause", String]` output is `{Press any key to continue . . .}(,TextForm)`

Comment: By the way, I think you mean to have `pr, "Program", ` in your `TextCell` expression.

Comment: What happens if you use `GFortran[inp_, _] := ` and `CellEvaluationFunction -> GFortran` ?

Comment: It worked! Changed to `GFortran[inp_, _]` now everything compiles.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the `CellEvaluationFunction` is supposed to accept two arguments, the second being the format type, I recommend defining:

```
GFortran[inp_, _] := . . .
```

and then using it directly:

```
CellEvaluationFunction -> GFortran
```